# Need an estimate of the max power density

Tags: layer1, fiber, optics, optical, passive-optical-network

Here is an image of a 1x64 fiber optic splitter/combiner:

[image]

I am assuming these are plastic/polymer fibers. A very similar box (http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/SC-UPC-1x32-Fiber-Optic-Splitter-PLC-Splitter-Module-SM-1M-Please-see-Options-/141150409820?hash=item20dd38545c:g:ao0AAOSwr81UOap3) permits 300mW of max optical power. Does this power rating seem reasonable and why?

Comment: You don't provide a manufacturer or model. How are we supposed to be able to answer this question? Also, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: I was looking for advice from people with experience. Tried getting help from Engineering but they pointed me to this forum. I saw many fiber-optic questions here. Can you please unhold my question.

Comment: If you edit your question to ask something which can be answered and remove the off-topic request for a recommendation, your question will automatically come up for a reopen vote. Questions seeking primarily opinion-based answers are off-topic here. You should read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for guidance on how to ask a question for experiences. The [help] has guidance on what to ask and how to ask it.

Comment: The question was edited, there is a numerical criterion in it now.

Comment: @RonMaupin His question has currently 4 VtCs on the Engineering SE, and I suggested him this site for a next try :-(

Comment: @RonMaupin If it is not network engineering, then what is that?

Comment: @user7641 I am sorry. My next idea: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com . There are various, accepted methods to heighten your answer results: 1) you can take apart your question to a networkengineering and to a hardware recommendation (and maybe to an engineering) part, and ask the on-topic parts on the different sites. 2) you can link to the questions on the other sites, either in the question body or in comments (putting in a "Related hardwarerecs/networkengineering/engineering question" link).

Comment: @user7641 Don't worry on the closed questions, you can still edit and comment them (and thus, refer to the questions on the alternate sites).

Comment: I edited your question to remove the request for a recommendation. As I explained a couple of times, product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as they are on most SE sites.

Comment: @peterh, I never said it was not network engineering. The original question had two very different problems. Product or resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as they are on most SE sites, and the question asked for a recommendation. Also, the question asked about specific power allowed by a device which was not identified by vendor or model. That was an impossible question to answer unless the answer was an opinion, and primarily opinion-based answers are also explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Plastic fiber seems like a very poor assumption here, IME.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the manufacturer claims 300 mW power output, then why would you think the power rating is not reasonable? Unlike the mass market for UTP cables, where you see all kinds of crap sold, optical splitters have a very small, contained market, and getting a bad reputation in that marketplace will spell doom.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off assuming these are not plastic/polymer since yellow = single mode = long haul = glass.  See [Plastic optical fiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_optical_fiber)

> the IEEE has not yet passed any of the proposals into a final extension of the existing ethernet standards.